# Replacing a specific word on a web page (only one word instance, not all of them)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that uses a context menu click handler on selected text to replace the selected text. Basically switching words.

The context menu handler receives the selected text, but not its element or HTML. Meaning I don't have access to the specific instance of the text on which the user has clicked, but I know what it is.

I could search the entire page for the selected text, but words often appear more than once in a webpage, and I'd like to replace only one of the word instances

For example,

```
<div id="One">
  This is a text
</div>
<div id="Two">
  This is another text
</div>
```

I need to distinguish between a click when the word "Text" on div One is selected and a click when the word "Text" on div Two is selected.

Is there a way to do so?

(The next problem of course will be to distinguish between same words in the same element, but I'm not sure that's possible at all)

Comment: Using your HTML as an example would something like this help at all:

    `document.querySelector('body').onclick = function clicked(event) {  
      if (event.target.textContent.match(/text/)) {  
        alert('text was found in ' + event.target.id);  
      }  
    }`

Comment: Have you tried to use `Document.querySelector()` - `innerHTML` ? this property provides a simple way to completely replace the contents of an element. Here's the documentation for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: I ended up getting the `window.getSelection().focusNode` on mouse clicks. That's the most reliable way I found. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `window.getSelection()` like so:

```
var selectedNode = $(window.getSelection().focusNode);
var textToReplace = window.getSelection().toString();

var replaced = selectedNode.html().replace(textToReplace, newText);
selectedNode.html(replaced);
```

I needed to get the selection on every click, so I registered on the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).click(function clicked(event) {
        RefreshSelection();
    });
});
```